# What is the equivalent of Row_Number() Over (Order by ) in DAX?

Tags: dax, azure-analysis-services

I am new to DAX and I'm finding a way to get the output of below sql query

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY arrdate, 
                         clientcode, FOP) AS BookingNumber

Please help me on this.

Comment: Take a look at RANKX: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/rankx-function-dax

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I have checked RANX function still I'm not able to understand where the order by part should be used?

Comment: Then post sample data and desired results in your question.